# Sorting a .txt file by name in python

Tags: python, sorting, blast

I have a huge blast output file in tabular format. I want to sort my data according to protein names, to see which seq-s align to that particular protein. Let's say I have

```
con19 sp|Q24K02|IDE_BOVIN 3
con19 sp|P35559|IDE_RAT   2
con15 sp|Q24K02|IDE_BOVIN 8
con15 sp|P14735|IDE_HUMAN 30
con16 sp|Q24K02|IDE_BOVIN 45
con16 sp|P35559|IDE_RAT   23
```

I want to get an output,both are OK

```
sp|Q24K02|IDE_BOVIN con19 3            sp|Q24K02|IDE_BOVIN con19 3
                    con15 8            sp|Q24K02|IDE_BOVIN con15 8
                    con16 45           sp|Q24K02|IDE_BOVIN con16 45
sp|P35559|IDE_RAT   con19 2            sp|P35559|IDE_RAT   con19 2          
                    con16 23           sp|P35559|IDE_RAT   con16 23
sp|P14735|IDE_HUMAN con15 30           sp|P14735|IDE_HUMAN con15 30



f1 = open('file.txt','r')
lines=f1.readlines()
for line in lines:
    a=sorted(lines)
    r=open('file.txt','w')
    r.writelines(a)
f1.close
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have tried to do an alphabetical sort, using sorted(), works for small files, but doesnt seem to work on my huge file

Comment: f1 = open('file.txt','r')
    lines=f1.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        a=sorted(lines)
        r=open('file.txt','w')
        r.writelines(a)
    f1.close

Comment: Ok, can you add this to your question? So we can see, where the problem is exactly. It seems you already know how to read and write files, which is the trickiest thing here.

Comment: sorry to write the scrip this way,cannot write in 'answer' part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling sorted once for each line (i.e. inside the loop), not for the *entire* set of lines. Try this instead:

```
f1 = open('file.txt','r')
a=sorted(f1.readlines(), key=lambda l:l.split('|')[1])
r=open('file.txt','w')
r.writelines(a)
f1.close
```

Comment: This code sorts the lines by the initial first column, but they should be sorted by the initial second column.

Comment: I need to sort the entire line but according to column 2,which is the name of proteins

Comment: @user3224522 OK the file will now be sorted by the second 'column'. Do you understand why you don't want to call sorted inside the loop?

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort on the middle element, just sorting the lines themselves will do an alphabetical sort i.e. on the first element.  Try this instead:

```
with open('infile.txt') as f_in, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(''.join(sorted(f_in, key=lambda x: x.split()[1:2])))
```